# Trigger job on Jenkins with some conditions

Tags: jenkins, triggers

I want to trigger job B while I click on  job A. While Job B successfully go to infinite loop (run forever), Job A is trigger. Moreover:
If Job B is failed or aborted, Job A also failed.
If Job A is failed or aborted, Job B is aborted.

Comment: Can you please ask your question again. Couldn't able to understand.

Comment: how to run the main job, while the triggered job is running

Comment: `Build Triggers` => `Build after other projects are built` I do think you know this. If this is your question is about?

Comment: I known Build Trigger, but I want to know more about how to add variable to trigger a new jobs.